# Drupal 7 Rules: Compare Group Reference Field and fire Rule if data changed

Tags: rules, entities, organic-groups

I am using a content type called **"question"** which has an organic group reference field (`og_group_ref`).

I want to trigger an action with Rules, when the field "`og_group_ref`" is changed on node update.

So I have created the following rule:

```
{ "rules_notify_question_author" : {
"LABEL" : "Question has moved - notify user",
"PLUGIN" : "reaction rule",
"OWNER" : "rules",
"REQUIRES" : [ "rules" ],
"ON" : { "node_update--question" : { "bundle" : "question" } },
"IF" : [
  { "AND" : [
      { "NOT data_is" : {
          "data" : [ "node-unchanged:og-group-ref" ],
          "value" : [ "node:og-group-ref" ]
        }
      }
    ]
  },
  { "NOT data_is_empty" : { "data" : [ "node:og-group-ref" ] } }
],
"DO" : [
  { "mail" : {
      "to" : "[node:author:mail]",
      "subject" : "Some handy subject",
      "message" : "E-Mail to author",
      "from" : "[site:mail]",
      "language" : [ "" ]
    }
  },
  { "drupal_message" : { "message" : "Message text" } } } }
]
```

The idea is that the author of a question gets notified, when the questions was moved to another group. The logic should be like this:

> **EVENT**: On Node question Update
>
> **CONDITION**: node_unchanged:og-group-ref != node:og-group-ref AND node:og-group-ref != EMPTY
>
> **ACTION:** Send Mail an show a message

My problem is, that the rule fires when the content of the field og_group_ref was changed and when it was NOT changed.

I printed the compared values in the drupal message. The values are correct. But I do not know, why the rule is triggered although the field "`og_group_ref`" did not change.

Has anyone an idea?

Comment: The problem seems to be, that the compared datas are objects and these are always different. If i compare the field og_group_ref:0:nid rules returns arrays with different indices so you can not compare the values. I will create my own rule programmatically

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem by creating an own condition for rules using the API of the rules module.

```
function hook_rules_condition_info() {
  return array(
    'rules_condition_text_compare' => array(
      'label' => t('Textual comparison'), 
      'parameter' => array(
        'text1' => array(
          'label' => t('Text 1'),
          'type' => 'text',
        ), 
        'text2' => array(
          'label' => t('Text 2'),
          'type' => 'text',
        ),
      ), 
      'group' => t('Rules'),
    ),
  );
}
```

See [hook_rules_condition_info](http://drupalcontrib.org/api/drupal/contributions!rules!rules.api.php/function/hook_rules_condition_info/7) for more details.